# Select not working properly with jQuery Steps

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-steps

So I'm making a form with jQuery Steps but select isn't working properly. When I pick from the dropdown, nothing happens. The default option is still the one that is selected.

I'm using https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/ for the selection.

js code:

```
$('#wizard_vertical').steps({
    headerTag: 'h3',
    bodyTag: 'section',
    transitionEffect: 'slideLeft',
    stepsOrientation: 'vertical',
    onInit: function (event, currentIndex) {
        setButtonWavesEffect(event);
    },
    onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, priorIndex) {
        setButtonWavesEffect(event);
    }
});
```

Also, select works properly outside the form.

I really have no idea how to fix this so help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's `jQuery Steps`?  Can you make a snippet (edit and click `[<>]`) with all the relevant `script src=` and `<link rel="stylesheet"` with code that works.   Also, please elaborate on *"not working properly"* - is it working at all?  What does it do / not do that you don't want it to / do want it to?

Comment: @freedomn-m http://www.jquery-steps.com/ also by not working properly I mean I can't select anything

Comment: I've added the tags to the question for you - which version of bootstrap as it seems to be relevant, probably which version of jquery as well.  (hence the request for a snippet with *all* relevant `script src=`)

Comment: @freedomn-m i'm using bootstrap v3.3.6 jquery v1.12.4 and jquery steps v1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Load [the selectpicker](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) with javascript after [jquery-steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/) has been initialized.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="lst-currency">Currency</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="lst-currency" title="Currency (All)">
    </select>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
// initialize your steps wizard
initSteps();

// initialize selectpicker element with JS

let options = [];
options.push('<option value="MMK">MMK</option>');
options.push('<option value="USD">USD</option>');
$("#lst-currency").html(options).selectpicker('refresh');
```

Or just call the [refresh method](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh)

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="lst-currency">Currency</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="lst-currency" title="Currency (All)">
     <option value="MMK">MMK</option>
     <option value="USD">USD</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
// initialize your steps wizard first
initSteps();

// call 'refresh' method of bootstrap-selectpicker   
$("#lst-currency").selectpicker('refresh');
```